# Find a record that belongs to another

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

A "user" has_many "foods", but only one food is marked as "favorite". Given a user, how can I find their favorite food or `nil` if no favorite food exists?

Users Table

```
id, email:string
```

Foods Table

```
id, user_id:integer, name:string, is_favorite:boolean
```

Possible solutions:

1. I could do `Foods.where()` and fill in criteria for the user and the `is_favorite` field. But this doesn't seem like the best activerecord way. See #2.
2. I could try to find it by traversing the objects, which seems like better code to me:  `@favorite_food = current_user.foods.???` But I'm not sure how to find the favorite.

**It's important your answer returns a falsey value and not an error if no foods have been listed.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a try with the following code

```
@favorite_food = current_user.foods.where(is_favorite: true).first
```

Comment: It's possible the user hasn't listed any foods yet. If that is the case will I get an error? 
`
@favorite_food = current_user.try(:foods).where(is_favorite: true).first`

Comment: No it won't give you any error, if user hasn't added any foods. This query in that case returns `nil`. This active record query runs the sql: select * from foods where user_id = 23 and is_favorite = true . so it is not going to throw any error.

Answer (score 0):

Just do this

```
current_user.foods.where(is_favorite: true)
```

BTW you can have a look at sql it generates by

```
p current_user.foods.where(is_favorite: true).to_sql
```

Answer (score 0):

How about a scope in `Food` model

```
class Food < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :favorite, -> { where(is_favorite: true) }
end
```

and using it in the controller

```
@favorite_food = current_user.foods.favorite # Which gives you the array of favorite foods for the user.
```

if there is no favorite food(i.e,`is_favorite=>false`),then `@favorite_food` will be `nil`

Answer (score 0):

To make it neater, you'll want to look at [ActiveRecord Association Extensions](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#association-extensions) (so you define your method in your `User` model, not `Food` model):

```
#app/models/user.rb
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :foods do
       def favorite
           where(is_favorite: true)
       end
   end
end

#-> current_user.foods.favorite
```

or you could use an instance method as to only call one method:

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    def favorite_foods
        joins(:foods).where(is_favorite: true)
    end
end

#-> current_user.favorite_foods
```